# Errors using Git and SourceTree

Tags: git, sourcetree

I keep getting this error message when I try to clone a site from Git to SourceTree:

warning: templates not found C:\Program Files\Git\share\git-core\templates

error: no such remote ref refs/heads/master.

I have already uninstalled SourceTree once. How do I fix this error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Just to let you know, your question as it stands doesn't provide us with enough detail. We appreciate relevant samples of your code, in this case, of the command you are using that is generating the error. If you are not using any code/commands at all, (i.e. if this is simply a software question), then it probably doesn't belong on this site.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a problem in Sourcetree, have you tried cloning using terminal?

also check here,

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/269610/sourcetree-git-cloning-warning-templates-not-found